# Cron Job is not running on EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have searched the community questions before posting this and tried the suggestions to no avail.
I am confused as to why my cron jobs in my ec2 are not getting triggered.

I ran the following in my ec2:

```
sudo service crond start
sudo crontab -e
```

Here I added the following:

```
30 7 * * * root /usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/hello-world.py
```

The python script creates a file on running. The job is not running as scheduled.
Please suggest me what I am missing here.

Comment: Amazon EC2 instances run with UTC timezones. Therefore, it will run at 7:30am UTC. Did you adjust that time for your personal timezone?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, I have made the adjustments accordingly and that cron time has elapsed without the cron job getting triggered.

Comment: You might want to redirect output and errors to a file to see if it is actually executing by adding a redirect at the end: `/usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/hello-world.py &> /tmp/hello.out`